# Extend simplicial homeomorphism in a PL surface

Tags: algebraic-topology, surfaces, simplex, simplicial-complex

Let $S$ be a connected PL closed surface. How can I show that, given a 2-simplex $\Delta$ in $S$ and a simplicial homeomorphism $g:\Delta\to \Delta$ that preserves orientation, this can be extended to a simplicial homeomorphism $h:S\to S$ ?

EDIT:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it preserves orientation, your homeomorphism is going to be a rotation of the simplex. Take a narrow annulus $A$ surrounding $\Delta$ with one boundary component $\partial_0A$ equal to the boundary of the simplex $\Delta$. Now we want to extend $g$ from $\partial_0A$ to $A$ in such a way that it restricts to the identity on $\partial _1A$. To do this note that $g|_{\partial_0A}$ is a rotation, and hence isotopic to the identity. Use the annulus $A$ to actually parametrize this isotopy. Now extend to all of $S$.

Comment: In the annulus $A$ there are also some "pieces" of 1-simplices of $S$, where do I map them?

Comment: @user72870: What do you mean by pieces of $1$-simplices? The inner boundary of the annulus is exactly the three $1$-simplices of $\Delta$. They get mapped to themselves by $g$. This rotation is then gradually undone as you move from the interior boundary of $A$ to its outer boundary. Imagine that the simplex and $S\setminus \Delta\cup A$ is made of a rigid material and the annulus is stretchy. Now imagine rotating $\Delta$. The stretchy material stretches to allow you to do this.

Comment: I've added a picture to my question. It's a portion of the triangulation of $S$. The blue triangle is $\Delta$ and the red zone is the annulus $A$. As you can see, in $A$ there are some pieces of $1$-simplices of $S$. I want a simplicial homeomorphism of $S$ into itself, where do I map that pieces?

Comment: @user72870 Subdivide first! You are not going to be able to use the original triangulation in general.

Comment: Ok, now it makes much more sense!